# Deserializing no array json object to dictionary in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to deserilaize json to a c# class. I am not sure how I can get the ErrorContent into Dictionary of key value pair? Since Error Content is not an array, can I still convert it to Dictionary?

When I try below code, I keep getting ErrorContent as null..

```
    var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SearchResponse>(jsonResponse);
```

The class Search Response looks like

```
public class SearchResponse
{
    public ErrorContent Errors { get; set; }
}

public class ErrorContent
{
    public Dictionary<int, string> Errors { get; set; } = new Dictionary<int, string>();
}
```

Sample json looks like

```
    {   
    "statusCode": 1233,   "status": "ERROR",   "payloadType": "ERROR", "payload": {
    "ErrorContent":{
       "101": "Value cannot be null",
       "102": "Value should always be integer"
    }}}
```

Comment: You're missing the `payload` property, of which `ErrorContent` is a child. It's also named `ErrorContent` in the JSON, so you likely want your C# property to be named the same. Use a service like https://jsonutils.com/ to convert your JSON to C# classes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I deserialize JSON to a simple Dictionary<string,string> in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207731/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-a-simple-dictionarystring-string-in-asp-net)

Comment: You can decorate your model with correct JSON properties. Response contains `payload` property, which has `ErrorContent` that can be parsed to `Dictionary<int, string>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your model like this. Your JSON and C# model are not correctly binding due to wrong models

```
  public class SearchResponse
    {
        [JsonProperty("payload")]
        public PayLoad PayLoad { get; set; }
    }

    public class PayLoad
    {
        public Dictionary<int, string> ErrorContent { get; set; }

    }
```

**Binding Steps**

1. First your model will look for `SearchResponse`  class
2. Then it will look for a class named `payload`
3. Then it will look for a dictionary with name `ErrorContent`

Comment: prob here is that I see all the values except for the dictionary.. Its always null. SO I am not sure if this can ever be converted to dictionary since it doesnt have [ ]??

Comment: I have tried it by myself and it is working. No need to have [] for the dictionary